# Legend making scroll in aChartEngine

Tags: scroll, achartengine, legend

I have implemented charts in my Android app with the library aChartEngine.

If I want to see the chart in full screen and making a scroll down to display the legend how do I can do? Is that in graphs with many series with large legend, the chart looks very small ...

I have the chart in a LinearLayout.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the legend:

```
renderer.setShowLegend(false);
```

You can minimize the chart margins:

```
renderer.setMargins(new int[4]);
```